# How to add angularjs in a symfony2 project

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a problem installing angular in symfony that is already created
Is there a documentation or tutorial?
thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Claies thx to the off-topic question we got a great answer from Dan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the fact I agree with @Claies, I'm still providing you a simple example of how to integrate AngularJS in a Symfony application. I'm using Linux, I install symfony projects using the `symfony` command, and I'm using `bower` to install my 3rd party front-end libraries. You can use whatever you'd like, but those might differ in the way you use them.

1) install new Symfony project (if you don't already have one) using:

```
$ symfony new project_name version_number
```

2) in the root directory, create a new `.bowerrc` file, writing the directory in which you want `angularjs` to be installed:

```
{
    "directory":"web"
}
```

3) create the `bower.json` file, by:

```
$ bower init
```

4) install `angularjs` (no need to be 1.5.8, install whatever version you want):

```
$ bower install --save angular#1.5.8
```

5) include `angular.min.js` script in `base.html.twig` file (or any other file you'd like), and place the `ng-app` (or `data-ng-app`) inside `html` tag (or whatever html tag you'd need)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
...
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('angular/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

6) start using angularjs. Example (assuming you already have a Symfony route and a controller that renders the `page.html.twig` template):

```
# app/Resources/views/default/page.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {% verbatim %}
        {{ 'This is angularJS code!' }}
    {% endverbatim %}
{% endblock %}
```

## TL;DR

The simplest way of using AngularJS within a Symfony project would be to download, manually, the AngularJS library, place it in `web` directory, and link it in `base.html.twig` in the `javascripts` block:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('angular/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Remember to include the `data-ng-app` directive.